# Ignoring embeded spaces with AWK

Tags: csv, awk, space

I'm looking for a simple way to print a specific field with awk while allowing for embedded spaces in the field.

Sample:   `Field1 Field2 "Field Three" Field4`

I want to be able to do the equivalent to `awk '{print $3}'` but getting "Field Three" as a single field not two.

Update: More specifically, I need to get later fields not $3 but the space in #3 is what's messing things up. The number of spaces between the quotes in $3 is variable. I'm just wanting to be able to treat what's between quotes as a single field even if not all fields are quoted. So, ignoring the spaces as field separators if between quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if the double quotes are always there:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

Specifically, I am telling `awk` that the fields are separated by double quotes, at which point the part you want is readily available as field 2.

If you need to get at subsequent fields, you can split the remainder of the line on spaces and get a new array, say `F[]` of fields, like this:

```
awk -F\" '{split($3,F," ");print $2,F[1],F[2]}' file

Field Three Field4 Field5
```

assuming your file looks like this:

```
Field1 Field2 "Field Three" Field4 Field5 Field6
```

Comment: Yes this gives me exactly field 3, but can't get later fields.

Comment: I didn't realise you wanted later fields too. I have added a way of coping with that, so please have another look.

Comment: Awesome. That gives me the trick that I need and was able to adjust it to the real data. (27 fields, multiples with quoted spaces.) [Sorry for being a paranoid security guy.] Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html), in `gawk` maybe you can use something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{print $3}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
"Field Three"
```

It may need more work to get suited to your needs completely.

I think it needs `gawk` 4+, https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-06/msg00013.html

Comment: This seems to have the exact same effect as just basic {print $3}. I get the first 1/2 of #3.

Comment: @Chris-9090, it is `gawk` specific, and needs version 4 or later. Are you using GNU awk (`gawk`) or some other implementation? Try `awk --version` to see which implementation you are using. For this to work the output should be see something like `GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Parsing CSV can be a tricky business. I like to use a language with a proper CSV parsing module. For example with ruby, parsing the given line, using space as the column separator, and default double quotes quoting character:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'row = CSV.parse_line($_, {:col_sep=>" "}); puts row[2]' <<END
Field1 Field2 "Field Three" Field4
END
```

```
Field Three
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to Ruby on this system.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Setchell's answer is good, although it will not work if you don't know in advance how many embedded quotes you have (and it doesn't split on spaces anymore).

I hacked this together (obviously it can be improved):

```
gawk -v FIELD=2 '{ a=$ FIELD; if (substr(a, 0, 1) == "\"") { gsub(/^\"/, "", a); s=a; for (i = FIELD + 1; i <= NF; i++) { a=$ i; nbSub=gsub(/\"$/, "", a); s = s " " a; if (nbSub > 0) { break } } print(s) } }' <<<'allo "hello world" bar'
```

I would recommend using something else than gawk for this (maybe look into parsing the fields with your shell's IFS variable?).

Addendum: As I said above, this is not really the right tool for the job. For example, you can specify the first field with the -v FIELD=, but it counts fields based on AWK's separator (the embedded spaces are still counted).

Comment: Thanks all for the input, but none of these help me. 
Maybe I wasn't clear enough on my overall objective. (Tried to keep the question simple.)

More specifically, I need to get later fields not $3 but the space in $3 is what's messing things up. The number of spaces between the quotes in $3 is variable. I'm just wanting to be able to treat what's between quotes as a single field even if not all fields are quoted. So, ignoring the spaces as field separators if between quotes.

Any other ideas? This is obviously more difficult that I hoped.