# awk input file has space space in quotes

Tags: regex, awk

Good day.

Trying to learn some AWK to convert some Juniper firewall configs to Cisco or Palo configs.  Part of that is to parse the configuration.  I have a sample here:

```
set service "RDP" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 3389-3389 
set service "LDAPS" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 636-636 
set service "SOAPS" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 444-444 
set service "KEYS-ADMIN" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 9000-9000 
set service "WSUS-MDM" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8530-8530 
set service "WSUS-MDM" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8531-8531 
set service "WSUS-MDM" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8531-8531 
set service "HTTPS-MDM" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8443-8443 
set service "IPSEC - 4500" protocol udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 4500-4500 
set service "IPSEC - 4500" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 1433-1433 
set service "IPSEC - 4500" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 1433-1433 
set service "OKFTP" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 2169-2169 
set service "Bomgar 8200" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8200-8200 
set service "Cisco VPN" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 10000-10000 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 10000-10000 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 10000-10000 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 500-500 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 4500-4500 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + 50 src-port 0-65535 dst-port 0-65535 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 10000-10000 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 500-500 
set service "Cisco VPN 2" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 4500-4500 
set service "TrendMicro8080" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8080-8080 
set service "TrendMicro26980" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 26980-26980 
set service "TrendMicro26980" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 26980-26980 
set service "PenPal Test" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 522-522 
set service "HTTP8080" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8080-8080 
set service "HTTPS445" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 445-445 
set service "MOBILEIRON-TLS" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 9997-9997 
set service "MOBILEIRON-TLS" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 9998-9998
```

I saved this snippet of lines to a file named test1 and ran this command from the command line:

```
awk -F " " 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $3,$5,$7,$9}' test1
```

Although it MOSTLY worked out, the spaces contained inside the " " where seen by awk as valid spaces.  The output:

```
"RDP",tcp,0-65535,3389-3389
"LDAPS",tcp,0-65535,636-636
"SOAPS",tcp,0-65535,444-444
"KEYS-ADMIN",tcp,0-65535,9000-9000
"WSUS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8530-8530
"WSUS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8531-8531
"WSUS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8531-8531
"HTTPS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8443-8443
"IPSEC,4500",udp,0-65535
"IPSEC,4500",tcp,0-65535
"IPSEC,4500",tcp,0-65535
"OKFTP",tcp,0-65535,2169-2169
"Bomgar,protocol,src-port,dst-port
"Cisco,protocol,src-port,dst-port
"Cisco,2",tcp,0-65535
"Cisco,2",udp,0-65535
"Cisco,2",udp,0-65535
"Cisco,2",udp,0-65535
"Cisco,2",50,0-65535
"Cisco,2",udp,0-65535
"Cisco,2",udp,0-65535
"Cisco,2",udp,0-65535
```

Ideally, I would like to have awk ignore the spaces in the " ".  I guess I could add it as a regular expression?  Do I use the '!' somehow?  Not sure.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/q/26262265/3495601](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26262265/3495601)

Answer (score 1):

There are <strike>likely</strike> many ways to achieve your end result (<strike>maybe</strike> even one that is `awk` inclusive):

```
awk -F\" 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {split($3,F," ");print $2,F[2],F[4],F[6]}' test1
```

Another way that is possible is to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\("[^"]*"\)* \("[^"]*"\)*/\1,\2/g' test1
```

...or piped to `awk`:

```
sed 's/\("[^"]*"\)* \("[^"]*"\)*/\1,\2/g' test1 | awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $3,$5,$7,$9}'
```

**Output:**

```
"RDP",tcp,0-65535,3389-3389
"LDAPS",tcp,0-65535,636-636
"SOAPS",tcp,0-65535,444-444
"KEYS-ADMIN",tcp,0-65535,9000-9000
"WSUS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8530-8530
"WSUS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8531-8531
"WSUS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8531-8531
"HTTPS-MDM",tcp,0-65535,8443-8443
"IPSEC - 4500",udp,0-65535,4500-4500
"IPSEC - 4500",tcp,0-65535,1433-1433
"IPSEC - 4500",tcp,0-65535,1433-1433
"OKFTP",tcp,0-65535,2169-2169
"Bomgar 8200",tcp,0-65535,8200-8200
"Cisco VPN",tcp,0-65535,10000-10000
"Cisco VPN 2",tcp,0-65535,10000-10000
"Cisco VPN 2",udp,0-65535,10000-10000
"Cisco VPN 2",udp,0-65535,500-500
...
```

The awk solution was discovered after learning of [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26262329/499581).

Comment: I needed a while, but I've eventually understood the trick! the groups on the left and right hide the quoted spaces, ok, and because of the `*` quantifier you appended to each of them also the spaces between _current_ fields are changed... smart.

Comment: @gboffi, As it turns out my approach was a little more complicated than it needed to be (which I assumed), but glad you learned something. I posted an updated solution that deals exclusively with awk too :)